# Scipy Derivative

Tags: python, math, scipy

I have a question about the derivative function of Scipy. I used it last night and got some odd answers. I tried again this morning with some simple functions and got some right answers and some wrong. Here were my tests:

```
In [1]: def poly1(x):
...:     return x**2

In [3]: derivative(poly1, 0)
Out[3]: 0.0

In [4]: def poly2(x):
...:    return (x-3)**2

In [6]: derivative(poly2, 3)
Out[6]: 0.0

In [8]: def sin1(x):
...:     return sin(x)

In [14]: derivative(sin1, pi/2)
Out[14]: 5.5511151231257827e-17

In [15]: def poly3(x):
....:     return 3*x**4 + 2*x**3 - 10*x**2 + 15*x - 2

In [19]: derivative(poly3, -2)
Out[19]: -39.0

In [20]: derivative(poly3, 2)
Out[20]: 121.0

In [22]: derivative(poly3, 0)
Out[22]: 17.0
```

I checked the values of poly3 by hand and -2 = 17, 2 = 95, 0 = 15. So am I using the function wrong, or is there something wrong with the function. Thanks

Using: Python 2.7.3, IPython 0.12.1, Numpy 1.6.1, Scipy 0.9.0, Linux Mint 13

Answer (score 20):

As the documentation for `derivative` says:

```
derivative(func, x0, dx=1.0, n=1, args=(), order=3)
    Find the n-th derivative of a function at point x0.

    Given a function, use a central difference formula with spacing `dx` to
    compute the n-th derivative at `x0`.
```

You didn't specify `dx`, so it used the default of `1`, which is too large here.  For example:

```
In [1]: from scipy.misc import derivative

In [2]: derivative(lambda x: 3*x**4 + 2*x**3 - 10*x**2 + 15*x - 2, -2, dx=1)
Out[2]: -39.0

In [3]: derivative(lambda x: 3*x**4 + 2*x**3 - 10*x**2 + 15*x - 2, -2, dx=0.5)
Out[3]: -22.5

In [4]: derivative(lambda x: 3*x**4 + 2*x**3 - 10*x**2 + 15*x - 2, -2, dx=0.1)
Out[4]: -17.220000000000084

In [5]: derivative(lambda x: 3*x**4 + 2*x**3 - 10*x**2 + 15*x - 2, -2, dx=0.01)
Out[5]: -17.0022000000003

In [6]: derivative(lambda x: 3*x**4 + 2*x**3 - 10*x**2 + 15*x - 2, -2, dx=1e-5)
Out[6]: -17.000000001843318
```

Alternatively, you could increase the order:

```
In [7]: derivative(lambda x: 3*x**4 + 2*x**3 - 10*x**2 + 15*x - 2, -2, dx=1, order=5)
Out[7]: -17.0
```

Taking numerical derivatives is always a little troublesome.

Comment: Ah, thank you, I read through the documentation for it and didn't really understand it too well. It would be nice if they provided an example like this to show how the other options work. Thanks again